# how to re-download XCode?

Tags: xcode

Downloaded Xcode 5.0.1, and when I open it, a message tells me it needs to install more components. However, clicking Install does nothing and all I can then do is quit.

The app store won't let me download it again as it shows as Installed, and I can't successfully delete it, even using appcleaner.

So how can I work around this?

TIA

Answer (score 2):

Just go to [Developer Center Downloads](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action) and get it from there.

Answer (score 0):

Download XCode through the [Dev Center](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action), there you can get a .dmg file!